# Homework help: Finding the min speed for the normal to be zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors

PROBLEM: The pipe AB of length L is moving at a constant speed $v$. Find the min speed that is needed so that point $B$'s normal force is zero $N_B = 0$

[image]

[image]

The solution starts with:

$\bf{a}$$_b = \frac{v^2}{R}$$\bf{e}$$_y$

$\bf{a}$$_A = $$\bf{a}$$_B+\alpha $$\bf{e}$$_Z \times $$\bf{r}$$_{BA}-ω^2$$\bf{r}$$_{BA}$

The solution proceeds setting:

$ω^2 = 0$ whilst $\alpha$ is not zero. How can that be? Can someone help me understand what is going on. I don't seem to have the intuition concerning this one.

Comment: Why don't you think it is possible for a rotational velocity to be zero but the rotational acceleration be non-zero?

Comment: @KyleKanos because it just feels logical that if sth has acceleration it should also have velocity. I would love to hear your thoughts on the matter too!

Comment: Throw a ball up in the air, it has a constant acceleration of 9.81 m/s/s throughout but, at its apex, has zero velocity (when it changes direction). Similar thing can happen with rotational motion (e.g., a disk that is slowing down due to a deceleration, stopping & going backwards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answering your question

We can actually choose any "center of rotation" to calculate about. Suppose we describe this system by fixating on the point $A$ with $a$ being its position along the straight part of the track, specifically $a=0$ being the point in question where the wheel centered at $B$ enters the circular arc of the track. We'll say that from the perspective of $A$, point $B$ is an angle $\theta$ beneath the horizontal.

Using this as the center, the moment of inertia of the rod about its end is $I =m L^2/3$ and it experiences (assuming that normal force $N_B$ is indeed zero!) a constant torque $\tau = m~g~L/2$ (with the force $N_A$ not contributing because it goes through the center of rotation.)

Let me use dots for time-derivatives. At this particular moment the angular velocity $\omega = \dot\theta$ is zero because the beam has not yet started rotating, but the angular acceleration $\alpha = \ddot\theta$ is not zero because the pipe is beginning to change its angular velocity. More specifically, $\alpha = \tau/I = \frac32 g / L.$

So that's the simple answer. **Yes, a velocity can be zero when an acceleration is not.** It just can't *stay* zero, but it can certainly *be* zero. Something similar happens when you are rolling forward and throw your car into reverse; as you add gas, you reach a point where you are stationary relative to the ground (as you must: you go from travelling forwards to travelling backwards!) with a constant acceleration. Or, it's like throwing a ball into the air: eventually it comes to its maximum height, and at that particular instant its velocity is zero, transitioning from positive to negative: but afterwards it accelerates into a negative velocity.

## How to finish this problem without a fixation on acceleration

For this sort of "constant acceleration" (albeit *angular* acceleration) we always see a dependence on the acceleration times $t^2/2$ to get the derivatives right; so in fact $\theta = \frac34~g~t^2/L.$ This is important because we can see that point $B$ is located at coordinates $[x, y] = [a + L~\cos\theta, -L~\sin\theta].$ The normal force is a constraint force: it stops a point from entering a region. To make the normal force zero we need a trajectory which is not passing inside the disk $$[L+r\sin\phi, -R + r \cos\phi]\text{ for }0\le \phi \lt 2\pi\text{ and }0\le r \lt R.$$

What we really care about here is $\phi \approx 0$ where the small angle $\phi$ can leads to the approximate formulas, $\phi$ in radians, of $\cos\phi \approx 1 - \phi^2/2,\;\sin\phi \approx \phi.$ Similarly I have carefully chosen that $\theta \approx 0$ at this place too, so that $\theta$ is also approximated that way.

Now if point $B$ is *just barely not violating the constraints* then it must **mirror this boundary path** for small angles and times, so that our approximate boundary $[L + R~\phi, -R~\phi^2/2]$ must approximately equal our approximate position of $B,$ which is $[a + L~(1 - \theta^2/2), -L\theta].$ Writing $a = vt$ and $\theta = \alpha t^2/2$ gives two equations:$$\begin{align}R \phi =&\; v t &+ O(t^4)\\
R\phi^2/2 =&\; L~\alpha~t^2/2 &+ O(t^6).
\end{align}$$We see that all of the higher-order stuff is easily neglected with just $\phi = vt/R$ in the first expression, but this can be substituted into the second expression to give $$v^2 / R = L \alpha.$$
This confirms just what your existing equation shows.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I find your way of describing easy to follow. I understand the principle of throwing a ball up into the air as well as the previous example. I don't understand though how that applies to this problem. Could you please comment and explain why in this situation we have omega equal to zero :)

Comment: @Mathguy007 because it doesn't start out with any rotational oomph: up until it crosses over onto the circular part of the track the pipe has been flat, not rotating. Here's a way to see the value of $\omega$: imagine $v \to \infty.$ The pipe only feels the torque $mgL/2$ for a time $L/v,$ picking up an angular velocity $(g/v) mL^2/(2I),$ which goes to zero like $1/v$.  We can therefore ask "for very large v, as it flies off, does it have some steady-state rotation which is not tending to zero?" In this case, no: if you let $v$ get large it fires off like a blowgun dart, with no base $\omega$.

Comment: @ Chris Drost. I don't know who you are or what you do but you sure know how to explain things :) Thanks so much for your help!!!